I installed airflow through docker. When I am trying to run a command I am getting below error
I intsalled the airflow through docker. When I tried to run a simple DAG. It is not importing the PythonOperato and giving me the below error.It has to do something with the SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN but couldn't figure it out.
C:\Users\bolla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\airflow\__init__.py:36: RuntimeWarning: Airflow currently can be run on POSIX-compliant Operating Systems. For development, it is regularly tested on fairly modern Linux Distros and recent versions of macOS. On Windows you can run it via WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux 2) or via Linux Containers. The work to add Windows support is tracked via https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10388, but it is not a high priority.
  warnings.warn(
OSError while attempting to symlink the latest log directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\bolla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\airflow.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bolla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\airflow\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    settings.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\bolla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\airflow\settings.py", line 536, in initialize
    configure_orm()
  File "C:\Users\bolla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\airflow\settings.py", line 238, in configure_orm
    raise AirflowConfigException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: Cannot use relative path: `sqlite:///C:\Users\bolla\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\airflow\/airflow.db` to connect to sqlite. Please use absolute path such as `sqlite:////tmp/airflow.db`.
PS C:\DockerDesktopWSL\docker-airflow-master> $ export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow

